# NetLogo simulation recording: how to adjust the recording rate?

Tags: netlogo

I have implemented a dynamical system in NetLogo using rk4, which makes the updation extremely slow. I can't observe anything when see the model. Is there any efficent way to record the simulation.

I know not much about graphics what does frame rate mean, does increasing that be of any help?

From what I understand how NetLogo does it is it records each update of view and plays at a specified frame rate. But in my case I want the frame rate to extremely high like about 1k-10k frames per sec. So what I am trying to do, is depending upon the frame rate, make Netlogo record lesser snapshots of the view. 
I don't know if I am conceptual wrong somewhere.

So essentially a correlation btw the frame rate and snapshots of view recording to discard frames which may not have such a effect in the overall video playing at such high rate.

Comment: You've previously asked about movies, so I know you already know about that. What other kind of recording do you mean?

Comment: As for frame rate, you can read about it at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#updates

Comment: @SethTisue  Check the question now.

Comment: @SethTisue I am not sure if what I just mentioned makes sense. Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The human eye can only perceive in the neighborhood of 50-100 frames per second, so when you say you're interested in getting "1k-10k" frames per sec, I don't understand that part. If you mean you want "1k-10k" *ticks* per second, that would make more sense.

A "frame" is just one of the still images that make up a movie.

If you record a movie using `movie-grab-view` or `export-view`, you're free to call those primitives as often or as seldom as you like, according to any scheme you like. For example, instead of grabbing a frame every tick, you might only grab a frame every 10th, or every 100th tick. The resulting movie will go by 10 or 100 times as fast, since it will contain 10x or 100x fewer frames. Using this technique, you can get as high a ticks-per-second number as you want.

Example code:

```
repeat 1000 [
  repeat 10 [ go ]
  movie-grab-view
]
```

Comment: Yeah! I just looking for any workaround over the recording issue in the netlogo, do you happen any extensions that solve the issue? For example, does http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/video.html have the same issue?

Comment: The video extension does something else — it reads videos, it doesn't create them. I don't know of any other relevant extensions.